# Snowflake LAST_VALUE with dynamic condition

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parent-child, hierarchy

I would like to determine the parent of a child in a sorted hierarchy with groups. I was trying to use LAST_VALUE, but I cannot get a dynamic condition into it selecting the last value until now with hierarchy level -1 of current row within the partition.

Here is some sample data:

| Group | ID | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| A | 3 | 2 |
| A | 4 | 1 |
| A | 5 | 2 |
| A | 6 | 3 |
| A | 7 | 3 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 3 |
| B | 4 | 4 |
| B | 5 | 1 |
| B | 6 | 2 |
| B | 7 | 2 |

Desired output:

| Group | ID | Level | Parent ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | NULL |
| A | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 3 | 2 |
| A | 4 | 2 | 1 |
| A | 5 | 3 | 4 |
| A | 6 | 2 | 1 |
| A | 7 | 3 | 6 |
| A | 8 | 3 | 7 |
| A | 9 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | NULL |
| B | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 4 | 3 | 3 |
| B | 5 | 1 | NULL |
| B | 6 | 2 | 5 |
| B | 7 | 3 | 6 |

Thanks for any good idea!

Comment: Yet you don't explain the logic behind the hierarchy. For example why in group A, ID = 4 founds itself on level 2 instead of being on level 1 as per sample data? Can you provide more details in relation to that?

Comment: Thanks for the question. The hierarchy is a BOM hierarchy. ID 4 in group A is a parallel branch to ID 2, ID6 and ID9 in group A. The IDs are just examples. In reality the IDs are hashes and the table has a display order which defines the sequence (I did not show the hashes and instead used the display sequence as example IDs).

Comment: Can you share any SQL you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are possible SQL only solutions, but this JavaScript UDTF directly holds on to the most recent parent of each level in each group.

```
create or replace table T1 as 
select 
COLUMN1::string as "GROUP",
COLUMN2::int as "ID",
COLUMN3::int as "LEVEL"
from (values
('A','1','1'),
('A','2','2'),
('A','3','2'),
('A','4','1'),
('A','5','2'),
('A','6','3'),
('A','7','3'),
('B','1','1'),
('B','2','2'),
('B','3','3'),
('B','4','4'),
('B','5','1'),
('B','6','2'),
('B','7','2')
);

create or replace function GET_PARENT_FROM_LEVEL(ID float, "LEVEL" float)
returns table(PARENT_ID string)
language javascript --strict immutable
as
$$
{
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
        this.levelOwner = [1000];
        this.currentHighestLevel = 0;
    },
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        this.levelOwner[row.LEVEL] = row.ID;
        if (row.LEVEL == 1) {
            rowWriter.writeRow({PARENT_ID:null});
        } else {
            rowWriter.writeRow({PARENT_ID:this.levelOwner[row.LEVEL]});
        }
    },
    finalize: function (rowWriter, context) {/*...*/},
}
$$;

select "GROUP", "ID", "LEVEL", T2.PARENT_ID 
from T1, table(GET_PARENT_FROM_LEVEL(ID::float, "LEVEL"::float) over (partition by "GROUP" order by ID)) T2
;
```